# Por que esse menu não funciona na versão mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Eu estava procurando uns templates de menus/layouts e encontrei [esse](http://codepen.io/chriskirsch/full/XJVEag/) muito legal, mas quando eu passei o google para a visão de celular quando eu clicava no menu a 1a bolinha vinha e voltava, em vez de vir todas elas e ficarem ali até eu clicar no botão novamente.

Quero saber como posso fazer para esse menu funcionar corretamente em qualquer resolução de tela e em qualquer dispositivo. Creio que seja algo nesse mousedown no .JS, mas eu ainda sou newbie em JS/JQuery....

[Compilador online do próprio template: CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/chriskirsch/pen/XJVEag/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesse teu código ambos os eventos são disparados e o código anula-se. Podes detectar se é mobile e adicionar o evento certo, evitando misturar APIs:

```
var ev = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';
$('.parent2').on(ev, function() {
```

#### codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJewqj

Comment: Funcionou e com 1 linha de código a mais, perfeito. Eu só mudei o `mousedown` por `click` por desencargo de consciência.

Answer (score 1):

O menu está funcionando, mas no celular o evento é ativado diversas vezes, dando a impressão de que o menu está travado. Isso fica mais evidente mudamos a cor do botão toda vez que o evento e ativado: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXjwWe

Para resolver isso, você pode fazer [como nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both), usando um timer para limitar o tempo em que o evento é ativado:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var active1 = false;
  var active2 = false;
  var active3 = false;
  var active4 = false;
    var flag = false;

    $('.parent2').on('touchstart click', function() {
        if (!flag) {
            flag = true;
            setTimeout(function(){ flag = false; }, 100);
            if (!active1) $(this).find('.test1').css({'background-color': 'gray', 'transform': 'translate(0px,125px)'});
            else $(this).find('.test1').css({'background-color': 'dimGray', 'transform': 'none'}); 
             if (!active2) $(this).find('.test2').css({'background-color': 'gray', 'transform': 'translate(60px,105px)'});
            else $(this).find('.test2').css({'background-color': 'darkGray', 'transform': 'none'});
              if (!active3) $(this).find('.test3').css({'background-color': 'gray', 'transform': 'translate(105px,60px)'});
            else $(this).find('.test3').css({'background-color': 'silver', 'transform': 'none'});
              if (!active4) $(this).find('.test4').css({'background-color': 'gray', 'transform': 'translate(125px,0px)'});
            else $(this).find('.test4').css({'background-color': 'silver', 'transform': 'none'});
            active1 = !active1;
            active2 = !active2;
            active3 = !active3;
            active4 = !active4;
        }
    });
});
```

Note que mudei as condições de eventos do `on` para `touchstart click`. Eu testei em meu celular e a função `click` também funcionou sem problemas.
Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPbwwg

Eu recomendo você deixar o tempo do `setTimeout` entre 500ms e 1000ms, assim dá tempo do menu começar a abrir e vê-lo funcionando, antes dele fechar repentinamente.